# Why we get inequality form an equation?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, proof-explanation, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

In the paper [linear forms in the logarithms of real algebraic numbers close to 1](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~bugeaud/travaux/ConfMumbaidef.pdf), it is written on page 5 that-

$\varLambda \leq \frac{1}{by^n}$ (see equation 7 on page 5)

But we get it from an equation. As I understand , it should be   $\varLambda = \frac{1}{by^n}$.

How   $\varLambda$ could be less than $\frac{1}{by^n}$?

If it is  $\varLambda \leq \frac{1}{by^n}$ then why not  $\varLambda \geq \frac{1}{by^n}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a=b$$ implies both $$a\le b$$ and $$a\ge b.$$

It's the author's choice to weaken the comparison for the requirements of the exposition.

---

**Quiz:**

Are these propositions true ? ($\land$ is and, $\lor$ is or)

- $a=b\implies a\le b\land a\ge b$ ?
- $a=b\implies a\le b\lor a\ge b$ ?
- $a=b\implies a< b\lor a=b\lor a> b$ ?
- $a=b\implies a< b\land a=b\land a> b$ ?

Comment: Seriously!  I am surprised!!

Comment: @MikeSQ: don't forget that $a\le b$ means "$a=b$ or $a<b$", whichever is true.

Answer (score 0):

From $$\tag6(b+1)x^n-by^n=1$$ we find after dividing by $by^n$
$$\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(\frac xy\right)^n-1=\frac1{by^n}.$$
This certainly *implies* (as long as $b,y>0$) that also 
$$\left|\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(\frac xy\right)^n-1\right|\le \frac1{by^n}.$$

Comment: If you don't mind I will ask the same question again as it is yet to be clear to me! Are you saying $$\left|\left(1+\frac1b\right)\left(\frac xy\right)^n-1\right|\geq \frac1{by^n}.$$ is not possible? Do you disagree  with Daoust's answer above?